# Getting Golf scores into an array

Tags: java, arrays

Hey guys I'm trying make a program that simulates a scorecard in Golf. I'm stuck with the arrays... 
I have a hole[] {0, 1, .... ,17} to counts a 18 hole course. But for each element in the array I think I'm going to need another array that takes the user's score for that hole.
I need help with incrementing the hole score( h1S, h2S, h3S...) because right now h1S is going to be reused for every hole so it's just going to rewrite itself right? lol anyways I'm lost, help me please.

```
static int hole[] = new int[18];
{

hole[0] = h1S; // hole Scores..
hole[1] = h2S;
hole[2] = h3S;
hole[3] = h4S;
hole[4] = h5S;
hole[5] = h6S;
hole[6] = h7S;
hole[7] = h8S;
hole[8] = h9S;
hole[9] = h10S;
hole[10] = h11S;
hole[11] = h12S;
hole[12] = h13S;
hole[13] = h14S;
hole[14] = h15S;
hole[15] = h16S;
hole[16] = h17S;
hole[17] = h18S;

}

public static void test1() 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (numPlayers == 1)
    {
        for (int holeNumber = 1; holeNumber < 19; holeNumber++)
        {
            System.out.println(player1 + ", Enter your hole " + holeNumber + " score.");
            h1S = input.nextInt();// i need increment h1S somehow *******************
        }
    }

    else if (numPlayers == 2)
    {
        for (int holeNumber = 1; holeNumber < 19; holeNumber++)
        {
            System.out.println(player1 + ", Enter your hole " + holeNumber + " score.");
            h1S = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println(player2 + ", Enter your hole " + holeNumber + " score.");
            h1S = input.nextInt();
        }
    }

    else if (numPlayers == 3)
    {
        for (int holeNumber = 1; holeNumber < 19; holeNumber++)
        {
            System.out.println(player1 + ", Enter your hole " + holeNumber + " score.");
            h1S = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println(player2 + ", Enter your hole " + holeNumber + " score.");
            h1S = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println(player3 + ", Enter your hole " + holeNumber + " score.");
            h1S = input.nextInt();
        }
    }

    else if (numPlayers == 4) 
    {
        for (int holeNumber = 1; holeNumber < 19; holeNumber++)
        {
            System.out.println(player1 + ", Enter your hole " + holeNumber + " score.");
            h1S = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println(player2 + ", Enter your hole " + holeNumber + " score.");
            h1S = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println(player3 + ", Enter your hole " + holeNumber + " score.");
            h1S = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println(player4 + ", Enter your hole " + holeNumber + " score.");
            h1S = input.nextInt();
        }
    }


}// end test1
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Forget array take an ArrayList. It is a dynamic array and you can have an aribtrary number of players. ArrayList can contain any object (other ArrayList) at any index.

Comment: @PeterMmm: Looking at the code, I think Du6e just started with Java and has gotten to the chapter of arrays. An ArrayList is still too advanced for her/him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do need a 2D array (if you want to keep score with arrays) but you could generate it programatically

```
int[][] score;

public Scorecard(int players){
  score = new int[18][players];
}
```

Then, to keep score, simply record `score[hole][playernum] = score`

Envision it as a grid with the x axis being the hole and y being the player. This method also allows you to record at each stroke, since you could increment it with `score[hole][playernum]++`