# Golf Score Tally Program Java - Stuck

Tags: java, arrays

So for my intro to Java course, I am supposed to create a simply golf-scoring program using arrays that looks like this:

(I'm stuck on the bottom portion when it comes to scoring all of my golf scores and tallying the results of the arrays...)

How many holes did you play? 9

Hole Pars

What is par for hole 1? 5

What is par for hole 2? 4

What is par for hole 3? 4

etc.

Your Scores

What did you shoot on hole 1? 4

What did you shoot on hole 2? 5

What did you shoot on hole 3? 3

etc.

---

Your scoring summary includes:

Total score: Par

Total holes-in-one: 0

Total number of double eagles (albatross): 0

Total number of eagles: 0

Total number of birdies: 5

Total number of pars: 1

Total number of bogies: 1

Total number of double bogies: 2

Total number of holes at 3 or more over par: 0

Here's the code I have to far,

```
/* Lab 4: Part 2 - Golf Score */

import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class golf_score2
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {

  Scanner m= new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner q= new Scanner(System.in);

  BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  System.out.print("How many holes did you play?");

  int h = m.nextInt();
  int hArray[] = new int[h];
  int pArray[] = new int[h];

  // Asks the user to enter par for i number of holes

  System.out.print("\nHole Pars");

  for(int i=0;i <h;i++)
   {
   System.out.print("\n\nWhat is par for hole " + (i+1) + "? ");
   hArray[i]=m.nextInt();
   }

  // Asks the user to enter score for i holes

  System.out.print("\n\nYour Scores");

  for(int i=0; i <h;i++)
   {
   System.out.print("\n\nWhat did you shoot on hole " + (i+1) + "? ");
   pArray[i]=m.nextInt();
   }

  System.out.print("\n\n---------------------------");
  System.out.print("\n\nYour scoring summary includes:");

  score_result = pArray[i] - hArray[i];

  System.out.print(score_result);

 }
}
```

Comment: Look at this answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24187709/getting-golf-scores-into-an-array?rq=1 for using a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: Here's a hint. This is a change to the last section of your class: `        for(int i=0; i <h; i++){
            int score_result = pArray[i] - hArray[i];

            System.out.print(score_result);

        }`

Comment: So I think that last part I added for "score_result" is completely wrong.  I like what jsh said about trying a 2D array, but I might have to reformat my code completely.  Essentially, the total score for each hole should be the (hole score - hole par).  I want to calculate the total, and I just don't know if it's possible using the code I have above.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to use another for loop to make sure you're tallying each score:

```
for(int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
    score_result = pArray[i] - hArray[i];
    System.out.print(score_result);
}
```

If you just want the final score it would look something like this:

```
int final_score = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
    score_result = pArray[i] - hArray[i];
    final_score += score_result;
}
System.out.println(final_score);
```

Comment: For some reason it still doesn't work, I know this is on the right track, but maybe something is wrong with the fact that I'm using two arrays...?  I'm pretty sure my "score_result" class is wrong and I still don't know how to fix the calculation to get the final score.

Comment: You should be fine using two arrays - you are keeping track of two different things (par values and scores). 2D arrays are more for tables of data.

Comment: Zachary, the code you gave spit out a couple errors in the compile process, not sure where from:

Comment: golf_score2.java:52: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable score_result
location: class golf_score2
    score_result = pArray[i] - hArray[i];
    ^
golf_score2.java:53: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable score_result
location: class golf_score2
    final_score += score_result;

Comment: Got it fixed, I think you were a lifesaver on this one.  Sorry for my beginner's confusion!