# Finding Golf Scores by a Tally Through JAVA Programming

Tags: java, xcode

So I have written this code, but am unable to find out why it is giving me an error for not defining 'i.' I thought I had in the loops I had created.Also, it is saying that my 'search_result' at the end of the code is undefined. Any help?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class golf_tally
{
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
 {
  Scanner m = new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner q = new Scanner(System.in);

  BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(System.in));

  System.out.print("How many holes did you play?");

  int h = m.nextInt();
  int hArray[] = new int[h];
  int pArray[] = new int[h];
  int hpArray[] = new int[h];

  System.out.print("\nHole Pars");

  for(int i = 0, i < h, i++)
  {
   System.out.print("\nWhat is par for hole " + (i+1) + "? ");
   hArray[i] = m.nextInt();
  }

  System.out.print("\n\You Scores");
 for (int i=0, i < h, i++)
  {
   System.out.print("\n\nWhat did you shoot on hole " + (i+1) + "? ");
   pArray[i]= m.nextInt();
  }

  System.out.print("\n\n--------------------");
  System.out.print("\n\nYour scoring summary includes:");

  score_result = pArray[i] - hArray[i];

  System.out.print(score_result);

  int holeInOneCount = 0;
  int doubleEagleCount = 0;
  int EagleCount = 0;

  if(pArray[i] == 1)
  {
   holeInOneCount++;
  }

  if(hpArray[i] == -3)
  {
   doubleEagleCount++;
  }

  if(hpArray[i] == -2)
  {
   EagleCount++;
  }
}
```

}

Comment: The scope of a variable declared in a `for` statement is the `for` statement body. Where are you using `i`?  What is `score_result` supposed to be? Where do you define it? Do you know what variable declaration is?

Comment: Always show us the full error message with such questions, not a paraphrasing of the message as the details are **very** important. It usually tells you **exactly** what is wrong and where.

Comment: What's xcode got to do with it?

Comment: So, looking again at your code, you've got multiple errors, and this suggests that your style of coding perhaps needs to be fixed. Don't type a large amount of code and then test it. Instead if you can't use a modern IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse (which warns you of compilation issues almost immediately), then it is up to you to compile your code **early and often**, and most importantly **to not add any new code until current compilation issues are fixed**. Else you'll end up with a rat's nest of hard to fix errors.

Comment: You must be in the same class as this guy from yesterday... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939953/golf-score-tally-program-java-stuck

Answer (score 3):

- `newInputStreamReader(System.in)` should be `new InputStreamReader(System.in)`
- `for (int i = 0, i  < h, i++) {` should be `for (int i = 0; i  < h; i++) {`
- `System.out.print("\n\You Scores");` should be `System.out.print("\nYou Scores");`
- `score_result = pArray[i] - hArray[i];` is wrong because `i` is not defined within the context you are tying to use it (you've defined within the context of the `for-loop`s, but those contexts no longer apply). I have the feeling that this should be calculating the sum of the two arrays and then generating a result by subtracting the two tallies from each other
- `score_result` is undefined